# store fixed bytes into byte array from input stream

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, bytebuffer

I'm trying to learn Java and I came across this practice problem in which I have to create a URL extractor. I am able to stream data and print it. However I'm not really familiar with the buffered reader therefore I need help with creating a buffer of 100 bytes, copying 100 bytes of data from the stream to this byte array, then process this part, then take the next chunk of 100 bytes from the stream and so on....

The following is my code and any help would greatly be appreciated.

I know that what i want needs to be done inside the while loop. I think I need to create a byte array and then store the data into it. It is the how I'm more interested in.

EDIT: I do not need the code sample for anything because I'm trying to learn. Only the description of how I can do this would suffice . Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you want to process bytes then why are you using a Reader? (Reader is for chars, InputStream is for bytes)

Comment: @immibis I'm not sure with how I need to go about this problem. But what I essentially want to do is read the characters from the stream, store them into the byte array until 100 bytes of data is reached. Then do whatever I want to do with this array and again fill the array with next set of characters until 100 bytes of data is filled in the byte array. 

Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a byte array (of the size you want) outside your while-loop (you can re-use it that way, so it's faster).
2. You can use a `BufferedInputStream` wrapped around your original `InputStream` instead of a `Reader` (as Readers can convert bytes to Strings, but we don't need that).
3. Then you can use the `read(byte[])` method of `BufferedInputStream` to copy the next series of bytes into the array. You can then process the retrieved bytes the way you want.

See [the API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) as a reference of what `read(byte[])` does.

Comment: Can you explain step 2 a little more please? How can I implement a BufferedInputStream instead of the BufferedReader in my code?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a `Reader` (and its subclass `BufferedReader`) is used to read characters not bytes. You should instead use a `BufferedInputStream` to read into a byte array of the specified size:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String website = "thecakestory.com";
    Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(website), 80);

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

    pw.println("GET /index.php / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    pw.println("Host: " + website);
    pw.flush();

    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());

    String x;
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] contents = new byte[100];
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(contents)) != -1) {
        x = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
        System.out.print(x);
    }

    client.close();
    pw.close();

}
```

Some useful links:

For an introduction to Java IO related stuff, see the Java tutorial page  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/. This should be the starting point for learning about streams, readers, etc.

For the documentation of `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedReader`, see their API reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: how can I set up a BufferedInputStream from the code given above? Can you explain this a little more? I'm sorry but I'm a noob to Java therefore can't figure out how this works?

Comment: Updated. You can create it by specifying the socket's input stream `client.getInputStream()`, a bit similar to the way you were doing with the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. Can you give me some links where I can read how both of these exactly work? I'm still unclear on what a BufferedReader or BufferedInputStream actually does.

Comment: Sure. I just added them.